# Extract a table from a MySQL dump with tac, grep and sed...in reverse

Tags: mysql, sed, grep

I was following [this guide](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/12/13/extracting-a-table-from-a-mysql-dump/) on extracting a table from a mysql dump with grep, so I wouldn't have to restore all 50GB of data to have a peek at one table. The two main commands to pull the table are:

```
 grep -n "Table structure" [MySQL_dump_filename].sql
```

which gets the line numbers for table definitions, then

```
 sed -n '[starting_line_number],[ending_line_number] p' [MySQL_dump_filename].sql > [table_output_filename].sql
```

I would like to search the .sql dump in reverse order though, as what I need is towards the end of the file and will take quite awhile to grep though the first 48GB of data. I'm on OS X and installed tac (via brew as noted [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6426)). But is it possible to setup the command to accomplish this and have it quit after sed grabs the needed lines? If not I might as well grep from the beginning and not tac at all, just wait it out. Or ctrl-c once I see the file populated in another terminal.

Example run:

```
$ tac dump.sql | grep -n "Table structure"
...
751:-- Table structure for table `answer`
779:-- Table structure for table `template`
806:-- Table structure for table `resource`
...
```

But of course those are the line numbers in reverse, so if you need the 'template' table you would need to sed -n '752,779 p', but from the end of the file otherwise you'll get the wrong line number (sed will count from the beginning of the file).

Comment: `grep` can smash through gigabytes of data in minutes, especially the newer GNU version. Why not do it in a single pass, though, using a scripting language like Ruby, Python or Perl?

Answer (score 1):

a few quick pointers:

- `dd` can help you to skip **very fast** N bytes/blocks/whatever if you are sure those first N gb are not usefull
- after skipping, no need to 1) `grep` to find line number then 2) `sed` to skip until line number n (reading twice the huge remaining): you could directly:

  `awk  '/beginningpattern/,/endpattern/ { print $0 ; }'` #warning: syntax uncomplete, better read about awk and its prowess. You can do all sort of neat stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more streamlined way to know where all table definitions begin and end.

For a give file `rolando.sql`, create a script that does the following:

```
DAT=rolando.sql
TBLMAP=tblmap.txt
TBLLST=${TBLLST}.lst
TBLTMP=${TBLMAP}.tmp
RUNMAP=DisplayTables.sh
grep -n "^-- Table structure" ${DAT} |sed 's/:/ /'| awk '{print $1}'  > ${TBLTMP}
grep -n "^) ENGINE="          ${DAT} |sed 's/:/ /'| awk '{print $1}' >> ${TBLTMP}
sort -n < ${TBLTMP} > ${TBLLST}
rm -f ${TBLTMP}
rm -f ${TBLMAP}
POS=1
for X in `cat ${TBLLST}`
do
    (( POS = 1 - POS ))
    if [ ${POS} -eq 0 ]
    then
        (( Y = X - 2 ))
    fi
    if [ ${POS} -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "${Y},${X}" >> ${TBLMAP}
    fi
done
rm -f ${TBLLST}
echo "Table Structures From ${DAT}"
for XY in `cat ${TBLMAP}`
do
    echo "sed -n '${XY}p' ${DAT}" >> ${RUNMAP}
done
chmod +x ${RUNMAP}
./${RUNMAP}
```

This script will output every create table statement for you. It will include the `DROP TABLE` statements also. If you do not want the drop table statements, you this one:

```
DAT=rolando.sql
TBLMAP=tblmap.txt
TBLLST=${TBLLST}.lst
TBLTMP=${TBLMAP}.tmp
RUNMAP=DisplayTables.sh
grep -n "^CREATE TABLE" ${DAT} | sed 's/:/ /' | awk '{print $1}'  > ${TBLTMP}
grep -n "^) ENGINE="    ${DAT} | sed 's/:/ /' | awk '{print $1}' >> ${TBLTMP}
sort -n < ${TBLTMP} > ${TBLLST}
rm -f ${TBLTMP}
rm -f ${TBLMAP}
POS=1
for X in `cat ${TBLLST}`
do
    (( POS = 1 - POS ))
    if [ ${POS} -eq 0 ]
    then
        (( Y = X ))
    fi
    if [ ${POS} -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "${Y},${X}" >> ${TBLMAP}
    fi
done
rm -f ${TBLLST}
echo echo "Table Structures From ${DAT}" > ${RUNMAP}
for XY in `cat ${TBLMAP}`
do
    echo "sed -n '${XY}p' ${DAT}" >> ${RUNMAP}
done
chmod +x ${RUNMAP}
./${RUNMAP}
```

Give it a Try !!!